# Why does this query return too many results?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query

```
Select * from tbl_schoolphotos where Filename like 
         'glasshouse_1_%' order by DateTaken
```

I would like to match

- glasshouse_1_20122204123455
- glasshouse_1_20122206102415

but not

- glasshouse_18_20122206102415

but its matching all three.  Anyone know why?  Does _ have special meaning in mysql?

Comment: Yes, the underscore is a wildcard that matches a single character. You can escape it with a \ (backslash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request must escape the underscore to work properly.

```
    Select * from tbl_schoolphotos where Filename like 
             'glasshouse\_1\_%' order by DateTaken
```

Info: The LIKE and NOT LIKE have two search helper symobls. The underscore _ character that looks for one character and the percentage % character that looks for zero or more characters.

And you don't want the underscore to be a search helper, you have to escape it with the `\` like `\_`.

Answer (score 5):

Because the underscore matches any single character

Comment: You can try escaping it with `\\`, like `glasshouse\\_1\\_%`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `_` in MySQL LIKE matches exactly one character.